# WebAPI methods not being recognized by the site hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am integrating a Single Sign on with our reporting vendor that validates a token by calling a web api method from their API. When I test this from my local machine with the API hosted locally, I can get to this web api method, the user gets validated with a valid token and the SSO works smoothly. When I publish this change to Azure, this validate method is not called, by which the SSO doesn't work. What am I missing or is there something I need to do in my app services in Azure to make sure this web api gets called. It for sure looks like this is skipped when published in Azure as this works perfectly fine on my local machine.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/reporting")]
public class ReportingAPIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("validateVendorAuthToken")]
    public UserInfo ValidateVendorAuthToken(string access_token)
    {
        var userInfo = Infrastructure.ReportingVendor.TokenAuthorization.GetUserInfo(access_token);
        return userInfo;
    }
 }
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then in my global.asax,

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

In order to call the ValidateVendorAuthToken, we supply the field values in vendor's API SQL database to match this route such as http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/reporting/validateVendorAuthToken, then the token gets generated.

To test in my local machine, I change this value to http://localhost:69808/api/reporting/validateVendorAuthToken.

Since this works locally, I have come to a conclusion that this web api method never gets called when the site is hosted in Azure. Is there something I would need to do in Azure or is there some thing I am missing on my application?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but do any of your field values contain a date?  I had an issue where testing on my local machine was fine but as soon as I deployed to azure it crashed and it turned out my UK formatted date was being interpreted as a month greater than 12 and bombing out without much of a clue.  Apologies for wasting your time if not!

Comment: Hi Adnan, welcome to SO! As this is currently formatted this is not an **answer**. Once you have enough reputation you will be able to leave **comments**. In the meantime please refrain from using **answers** for clarification purposes.

Comment: @Adnan: None of them do.